# Exclude issue to get the count with a subquery

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models.

**Item**

```
class Item:
   name = Charfield

class ItemCopy:
   orig = foreignkey(item)
   Copy = foregin key (item)
```

So I want to get the count of all items but I want to exclude if the Item id is existing in ItemCopy.copy. 
Item has no connection to ItemCopy but ItemCopy has a connection to Item.

Maybe like this:

```
Item.objects.exclude(itemCopy=item.id).count()
```

Anyone has an idea how I can exclude it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now over this way with a subquery.

```
Item.objects.exclude(id__in=ItemCopy.objects.values_list("copy", flat=True)).count()
```